# C# Random Password Generator

Tags: c#, random, encoding, ascii, numericupdown

Here is the code: (passwordLengthBox is a NumericUpDown Box, r and k are random numbers)

```
    private void generateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int r, k;
                int passwordLength = (Int32)passwordLengthBox.Value;
                string password = "";
                char[] upperCase = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
                char[] lowerCase = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
                int[] numbers = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
                Random rRandom = new Random();



                for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++)
                {
                    r = rRandom.Next(3);

                    if (r == 0)
                    {
                        k = rRandom.Next(0, 25);
                        password += upperCase[k];
                    }

                    else if (r == 1)
                    {
                        k = rRandom.Next(0, 25);
                        password += lowerCase[k];
                    }

                    else if (r == 2)
                    {
                        k = rRandom.Next(0, 9);
                        password += numbers[k];
                    }

                }

                textBox.Text = password;
            }
```

What this program does is to create a random password with letters (both upper case and lower case) and numbers at the length that I choose.
The problem is that the program does **not** make the password length as I chose.

For example: if I type 5 in the NumericUpDown Box (passwordLengthBox) that sets the Password Length sometimes its giving me passwords that are 5 chars long and sometime 6/7/8 chars long passwords.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you check that `passwordLength` contains the value you entered?

Comment: BTW: For clarity you should change the last `else if` to be just `else` with a `Debug.Assert(r == 2)`, or add a trailing `else` that has a `Debug.Assert(false)` or equivalent.

Comment: @MatthewWatson There is no chance to get anything but `0`, `1` or `2` from `random.Next(3)`, so simple `else` should be OK.

Comment: You can use `System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(int length, int numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters)` to generate random passwords.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
int[] numbers = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
```

With that declaration every time a number is appended into `password` it is taken as ASCII number, not a real value. So you're adding integers from 48 to 57, what makes result string longer then expected.

e.g. when `6` is generated as a random number, you're appending something like: `((int)'6').ToString()` into your `password` variable, what actually adds `54` instead of `6`.

Declare that array as `char[]` and it will works fine.

Comment: @Saurabh using "int[] numbers = {'0' ..." will store ASCII values. Hint is in "int[]"

Answer (score 11):

You could try this little method instead instead.

```
public static string Random(int length)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] result = new byte[length];
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
            result[index] = (byte)new Random().Next(33, 126);
        }
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
     }
}
```

The only difference with this is that it will use alphanumeric chars too, for example it may generate strings like `f6Dx3$5d£4hG7`

take a look at [www.asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/) and work out the character range you want to use.

For [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012969/nathan), here is another way you could do it, if you know exactly which characters you want...

```
public static string Random(int length)
{
    string allowed = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    return new string(allowed
        .OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())
        .Take(length)
        .ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to _this_ question. It wasn't "how to generate random password".

Comment: @HenkHolterman, indeed, however code simplicity can solve problems just as easily.

Comment: Need to sleep the thread, provide a different seed, or pull the `new Random()` outside the loop -- on a fast computer this results in the same character being repeated over and over. Otherwise pretty decent solution.

Comment: Is there a way to break up the range of this, result[index] = (byte)random.Next(33, 126);?  I need the range to be 48-57, 65-90, and 97-122.  Thank you.

Comment: @Nathan, see my update...that should do it for you. Since Guid.NewGuid() is (virtually) guaranteed to produce a unique value, it will scramble the allowed characters in the string, and then Take the given length.

Comment: @series0ne Thank you!  That works perfectly and is a lot less code which makes it even better!

Comment: Why catch the exception, just to throw it again?

Answer (score 4):

Here My Complete Function to generate random password with desired length
(thanks to Viacheslav Smityukh)

```
    private String GeneratePassword(int genlen = 21, bool usenumbers = true, bool uselowalphabets = true, bool usehighalphabets = true, bool usesymbols = true)
    {

        var upperCase = new char[]
            {
                'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
                'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
            };

        var lowerCase = new char[]
            {
                'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
                'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
            };

        var numerals = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

        var symbols = new char[]
            {
                '~', '`', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '{', '[', '}', ']', '-', '_', '=', '+', ':',
                ';', '|', '/', '?', ',', '<', '.', '>'
            };

        char[] total = (new char[0])
                        .Concat(usehighalphabets ? upperCase : new char[0])
                        .Concat(uselowalphabets ? lowerCase : new char[0])
                        .Concat(usenumbers ? numerals : new char[0])
                        .Concat(usesymbols ? symbols : new char[0])
                        .ToArray();

        var rnd = new Random();

        var chars = Enumerable
            .Repeat<int>(0, genlen)
            .Select(i => total[rnd.Next(total.Length)])
            .ToArray();

        return new string(chars);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slight improvement on the answer from [series0ne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033686/series0ne).  That answer gave a password with the same character.  (e.g. %%%%%)

```
        var random = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        try
        {
            var result = new byte[length];
            for (var index = 0; index < length; index++)
            {
                result[index] = (byte) random.Next(33, 126);
            }
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
var numberOfChars = 6;

var upperCase = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
var lowerCase = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
var numbers = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
var rnd = new Random();

var total = upperCase
    .Concat(lowerCase)
    .Concat(numbers)
    .ToArray();

var chars = Enumerable
    .Repeat<int>(0, numberOfChars)
    .Select(i => total[rnd.Next(total.Length)])
    .ToArray();

var result = new string(chars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option which allows connecting it to a button/textbox to generate passwords of a certain length, hope this is useful to someone, this was thanks to one of the above comments and some extra from me.

```
public static string Random(int length)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] result = new byte[length];
                for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
                {
                    result[index] = (byte)new Random().Next(33, 126);
                }
                return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
        public int control = 1;
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (control == 0) { yourPasswordBox.Text = ""; }
            control = Int32.Parse(yourLengthInputBox.Text);
            for (; control > 0;) {
                yourPasswordBox.Text = yourPasswordBox.Text + Random((1));
                await Task.Delay(1);
                control--;
                
            }
            
            
        }
```